# How to migrate the "hadoop jar" command to GCP?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, cloudera, google-cloud-dataproc

The title pretty much says it all: we are migrating some jobs from Cloudera to GCP, and to do so, among other things, we are replacing all the hadoop commands with the gsutil counterparts.

However, I have several difficulties with the hadoop jar command, because I have not found a valid replacement.

Say I have this in my old job:

```
hadoop jar /some/cloudera/path/thefile.jar \
    -files $path1/file1.sh,$path2/file2.py \
    -D mapred.job.queue.name=${ENVVAR} \
    -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
    -D stream.map.output.field.separator=";" \
    -input ${inputPath}/* \
    -output ${outputPath} \
    -mapper file1.sh
```

What would it be the best way to do the same actions on GCP?

(This is my first question, don't be mean :) )

**UPDATE:**

how true it is that you never stop learning! And above all that your old questions really sound stupid to you.
The simple solution was

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop \
  --cluster=[CLUSTER_NAME] \
  --region=[REGION] \
  --jar=file:///usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
  --files $path1/file1.sh,$path2/file2.py \
  --properties mapreduce.job.reduces=0,stream.map.output.field.separator=";" \
  -- -input {theInputPathButOnGs}/* -output {theOutputPathButOnGs} -mapper file1.sh
```

I probably couldn't figure it out at first because I didn't find a proper example, so I had to do some trying to figure out where to put the key=value parameters, as well as input, output and mapper. Everything seemed so different. But it worked. Thanks to those who helped me

Comment: It's the same command on GCP. I'm not aware DataProc can just run a standalone JAR without starting a cluster and running `hadoop jar` itself

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difficulties you're facing, any error messages? Here's the doc on how to run hadoop jobs with Dataproc https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/hadoop

Comment: @mERCER you're only option is to use Dataproc Workflow Templates https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/overview#workflow_templates_use_cases

Comment: *the problem is we are not executing on dataproc*. If  you are not using DataProc where you're trying to run your jobs?  Please attach an output you get after running the `hadoop jar` command.